# Properly terminate java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
neighboursOfCurrentVertexList = neighboursOfCurrentVertexList.stream()
            .filter(vertex -> !vertex.isMarked())
            .map(vertex -> {
                vertex.setMarked(true);
                queueToVisitVertex.add(vertex);
                return vertex;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have implemented this breadthFirstSearch algorithm using java streams. First, i filtered to check if the vertex is marked, then if it is not marked, i add it to the queue. When i am using the .map, i need to end off with a terminating operation like .collect(Collectors.toList()).

My question is that this does not look right to me because I am using collect which returns a new list of the filtered vertex. What terminal operation should i be using in this case? I have no need of collecting the new list. I just want to use the map operation that is all. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead of `.map`:

```
neighboursOfCurrentVertexList.stream()
        .filter(vertex -> !vertex.isMarked())
        .forEach(vertex -> {
            vertex.setMarked(true);
            queueToVisitVertex.add(vertex);
        });
```